# Making a REST Post Request Without Passing a Name/Id in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, rest

I have a situation - in my Angular 2 app with a Node/MongoDB backend API - where I want a user to be able to click an "Add Record" button, and have a REST post request send that info to the API in a way that creates the new record, and returns the id of the new record, which I can then use to navigate to that new record in the front end.

Here's the thing though: I know how to handle passing a name, or something like that, when making this network request, but how would I handle this post request when I have no initial info to send from the user?

Let me show what I'm used to working with.

First, here's the create post request from my service:

```
createRecord(name) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    const body = JSON.stringify(name);
    return this._http.post
    ('https://api.someapiurl?apikey=someapikey',
    body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

And then, in my component I'm doing this:

```
createRecord(name) {
    const id = {name: name};
    this.recordsService.createRecord(id).subscribe(
    data => {
        // refresh the list
        this.records();
        return true;
    },
    error => {
        console.error("Error creating record...");
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
    );
}
```

And I'm using a button in the view, like this:

```
<button md-button class="add-button" (click)="createRecord()">Add Record</button>
```

How would I handle a situation where I want to make a post REST request that creates a record, but does so without passing any info (i.e., no name or id, etc). Is this doable? Just to clarify, it's because the user is just clicking a button, they're not entering any values, that's why I'm not sure how to handle this. Can I pass some arbitrary value?

Comment: I did not understand what you want exactly but if you want to create a record you will need some data to create it. what is the reason not to sent any info and get the record created not clear to me.  ID can be self-increment in the database but not sure about the name.

Comment: The idea is that a user is just clicking a "Create Record" button. They're not entering any values. So what could I pass in this situation?

Comment: anything that you want if you have those data in scope. You need to create the request body on that click and make a post call

Comment: Such as? Can you give me an example?

Comment: when you say data what does the post call actually need in the body there must be a body it needs. You can store the data in local storage/session storage as well if you want to send that.  are you trying to figure out a way to get the data in the request body if yes then you need to have that data somewhere first right.

Comment: So are you saying this is not doable then? I need to have a user enter a name or something to be able to use a post request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137077/discussion-between-grinish-nepal-and-muirik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understood you want to create empty record without info? what happens when you set body as empty string? on the other hand, you can always do post without sending body. How is your REST controller on backend configured?

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I want to create an empty record, and then have the API return this newly created empty record id (because that should be auto-generated by the API), so that I can navigate to that, and then the user can THEN enter the info for the record.

Comment: Setting body to be an empty string is an interesting way to handle this. I will give that a try.

Comment: the API should be able to handle that then only it will work whoever is building the API should be able to tell you what to send to create an empty record.

Comment: @GrinishNepal exactly.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will check with our API guy to get this set up correctly between the front and backend.